# jqGrid is empty, I can see in firebug, ajax request from jqgrid returns the json data correctly

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can’t add data to jqGrid from php within json format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010403/cant-add-data-to-jqgrid-from-php-within-json-format)

I am trying to load the jgqgrid with data returned from Controller Action in asp.net. I am using MVC 3 with razor view engine. I can see in in fiddler as well as firebug that the ajax request made from jqGrid is returning data but the data is not getting displayed in jqgrid. I have looked at all the related psots and answers.
I made sure that locale file is specified before the jqgrid script file.
I have tried both GET and POST and changed the action attribute accordingly in controller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        url: '/Execution/GetAllExecutions/',
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: true },
        mtype: 'POST',
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 30],
        viewrecords: true,
        colNames: ['OrderID'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'OrderID', index: 'OrderID', align: 'right',key:true, width: 250}
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'OrderID',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",                                   
        caption: 'Orders'
    });
});
</script>

<table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>

<div id="pager"></div>
```

Comment: I added the following handlers   loadComplete: function () {
                    alert("OK");
                },
                loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '\n' +'textStatus: ' + textStatus + '\n' +'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
                     alert('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                     }, and loadComplete was executed, I get OK alert message.

Comment: You should append your question with the raw response from the server which you can see in Firebug. The `jsonReader` for example should corresponds the format of the response. Moreover the `ContentType` of the response could be also very important.

Comment: Here is the response from server- I get 200 ok [{"ExtensionData":{},"BrSeqID":1,"ClearingID":"ClearingId1","ContractMMD":"ContractMMD1","ExchangeType":"B","OrderAction":"C","OrderID":1,"Price":100,"Quantity":10,"ReportType":"A"},{"ExtensionData":{},"BrSeqID":1,"ClearingID":"ClearingId1","ContractMMD":"ContractMMD1","ExchangeType":"B","OrderAction":"C","OrderID":2,"Price":100,"Quantity":10,"ReportType":"A"}]

Comment: but the response from server dont math with the colModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the JSON response returned from the server don't corresponds to `jsonReader: { repeatitems: true }` which you use. You should use something like the following

```
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    root: function (obj) { return obj; },
    page: function () { return 1; },
    total: function () { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
}
```

Moreover would recommend you to add `loadonce: true` option because you seems don't implemented the paging on the server side.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have saved my day. I have been hitting my head hard for 2 days, it works now. I am new to jquery and first time using jqgrid.